# How to convert Timestamp from mysql into Date/Time object

Tags: ruby

I am fetching data from a mysql database in a non rails project using ruby. The data has a `TIMESTAMP` type, how can I convert it to a ruby date/time object so that I can do date comparisons on it?

These are some of the values coming from the db:

```
2014-03-17 22:56:02
2011-05-17 21:46:22
```

Comment: What is the data type you have on the Ruby side? The data type `TIMESTAMP` within the database does not directly matter.

Comment: @sawa my final goal is to compare it to today's date so I can get a string like "5 days ago"..."1 day ago" etc.

Comment: Are you on rails or Ruby ?

Comment: Idk why your question is being downvoted, even with rails 4 mysql's `datetime` will be converted to a Time object. From there you need still need to call `to_date`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`::strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime)

```
require 'date'

string = '2014-03-17 22:56:02'
DateTime.strptime(string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
# => #<DateTime: 2014-03-17T22:56:02+00:00 ((2456734j,82562s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
t = Time.at(<msqlTimestamp>)
puts t.to_date
```

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Time.html
So in this case the to_datetime would be what you need

Comment: But here I didn't find it - http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html

Comment: Ok.. But here -- http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Time.html .. Anyway thanks.